# Making ArcPy exclude frozen / off layers while importing DWG file?

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, autocad, dwg

I'm attempting to update existing GIS feature classes (SDE) using master AutoCAD files but end up importing ALL features present in the AutoCAD drawing regardless of the visibility settings (frozen / off) set in the DWG.

ArcMap recognizes the layer visibility settings if a DWG, how do I make arcpy do the same?

I'm using: arcpy.Append_management(,) to replace previously deleted features in the GIS.

```
outFC = "<outGDB>\\<outFC>"
inputDrawing = "<path>\\<file>.dwg"
inputLayer = os.path.basename(inputDrawing) + "_layer"
sqlExpression_CAD = "NOT \"Layer\" LIKE 'S_Grid%'" # This is what I want to avoid #  

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputDrawing,inputLayer,<layer information>)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", sqlExpression_CAD)
arcpy.Append_management(inputLayer, outFC, "NO_TEST")
```